# Only section heads in table of contents using beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

I'm new to making LaTeX presentation.

I'm using `beamer` type as [documentclass](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations). After the title slide, I have the table of contents slide. Now in the table of contents slide I don't want to show the subsection, but in the Outline slide that is shown at the beginning of each section I want to show the *section* and the *subsection* highlighted.

How do I do so?

This is the link to my [code](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52224cb7e77a8bec147d6c88). I read some of the questions here but none really satisfied my needs.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add `hideallsubsections` as an option to the main ToC, i.e.

```
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
```

Another way would be to uncomment `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`, and add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`right after the frame with the main ToC.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}


\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[F. Author]{F.author\inst{1}\and S. Autor\inst{2}}
\institute[University of Somewhere and Elsewhere] {
    \inst{1}
        UofS
    \and
    \inst{2}%
        UofE
}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{First Main Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{frame}{First Slide Title}{Optional Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    My first point.
  }
  \item {
    My second point.
  }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

% You can reveal the parts of a slide one at a time
% with the \pause command:
\begin{frame}{Second Slide Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    First item.
    \pause % The slide will pause after showing the first item
  }
  \item {   
    Second item.
  }
  % You can also specify when the content should appear
  % by using <n->:
  \item<3-> {
    Third item.
  }
  \item<4-> {
    Fourth item.
  }
  % or you can use the \uncover command to reveal general
  % content (not just \items):
  \item<5-> {
    Fifth item. \uncover<6->{Extra text in the fifth item.}
  }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Second Main Section}

\subsection{Another Subsection}

\begin{frame}{Blocks}
\begin{block}{Block Title}
You can also highlight sections of your presentation in a block, with it's own title
\end{block}
\begin{theorem}
There are separate environments for theorems, examples, definitions and proofs.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}
Here is an example of an example block.
\end{example}
\end{frame}

% Placing a * after \section means it will not show in the
% outline or table of contents.
\section*{Summary}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Outlook
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Something you haven't solved.
    \item
      Something else you haven't solved.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



% All of the following is optional and typically not needed. 
\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short. 

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```